# Changing ae, oe, ue into umlaut

Tags: r, gsub

I'd like to change ae, oe, ue into ä, ö, ü with gsub() but only when there is no vowel (a, e, i, o, u) coming before. I came up with this so far:

```
umlaut_conversion <- function(text){
  text <- text %>%
  {gsub('ae','ä',.)} %>%
  {gsub('oe','ö',.)} %>%
  {gsub('ue','ü',.)}  
}

umlaut_conversion('Neue Woerter!')
```

This has the following result:

```
Neü Wörter!
```

But the output which I need is:

```
Neue Wörter!
```

So because of the vowel 'e' in front of 'ue' in 'Neue' it's not supposed to change it. And it shall work for all vowels.

Comment: This is a complex problem that cannot be solved with regular expressions. You need a software that includes a dictionary and has sufficient understanding of German grammar.

Comment: Okay, thank you nevertheless. I think I figured out how to do it in a later step.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other cases that you have not described, but it is not hard to do what you said with a regular expression. The following makes the desired substitutions *except* when preceded by a vowel.

```
umlaut_conversion <- function(text){
  text <- text %>%
  {gsub('(^|[^aeiou])ae','\\1ä',., perl=T)} %>%
  {gsub('(^|[^aeiou])oe','\\1ö',., perl=T)} %>%
  {gsub('(^|[^aeiou])ue','\\1ü',., perl=T)}  
  text
}

umlaut_conversion('Neue Woerter!')
[1] "Neue Wörter!"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: This will break for compound words.

Comment: @Roland please give an example of a compound word that will make it fail.

Comment: Autoersatzteile

Comment: Ah,  I see what you are saying. You are saying that the rule given by the OP (oe not preceded by a vowel) is not always correct. That is why I said "_There may be other cases that you have not described_". The above implements his rule, but you are saying that the rule is not completely correct.

Comment: Yes, I've already said OP's task can't be done  (only) with regex.